# Trying to determine battery size with a TI BQ25504

Tags: solar-cell, texas-instruments

Currently I am trying to design a low power tracker in order to track cattle. I would like to implement a solar panel to keep the circuit powered. Through my research I found the Texas Instruments BQ25504 that can monitor and store the collected energy. The issue I am having is what to use for a battery. In the data sheet it gives an equation for the equivalent capacitance of the battery needed: 
A storage element
with 100 uF equivalent capacitance is required to filter the pulse currents of the PFM switching charger
 Ceq = 100uF = 2 x mAHr(Bat) x 3600 s/Hr / V(Bat) 
 After simplifying the equation I got: 
 (1F/72,000) = (X Amp Seconds)/V(Bat)
 So to me this says in order to have a voltage of 4.2V I would need a .085mA battery. To me that seems off in some way but I don't know if it was my math or does this BQ25504 indeed only allow very small batteries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, what that equation means is that a 100uF⋅3.7V ~= 0.00010277778 mAh Li-ion battery has the equivalent capacitance of a 100uF capacitor for the storage purposes of this device. If you want a larger storage element then use a larger battery.

Comment: So what does it mean when it says the storage element is required to filter the pulse currents? If I don't choose a battery that follows this will it have any adverse effects?

Comment: It means that without a storage element the voltage output can be very unstable since more current may be drawn than can be handled by the generation device.